# How to type curly braces / brackets { } with one click on M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to type { and } with one key stroke. I attempted to created a shortcut replacing [ and ] with { } on OSX Keyboard settings but turns out I need [] too. It seems like the only "extra" buttons are the right command and option but I can't seem to configure this shortcut. Would anyone know how?

Alternatively I was looking into this keyboard:
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english?afid=p238%7CsSjMWTNaO-dc_mtid_1870765e38482_pcrid_498267346774_pgrid_120246584840_&cid=aos-us-kwgo-pla---slid---product-MQ052LL/A

When I ask Apples sales reps if F13/14 can be changed to { } there is a very long pause and no answer.

Alternatively, is there another keyboard that supports this function?

I saw threads on this from almost 20 years ago but nothing recent!

Comment: How do you intend to do the remapping? The keyboard settings, as far as I know, don't allow you to repurpose any of the function-keys on MacOS.

Comment: I tried /System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources/ but couldn't find right control and option in the plist files

Comment: You should update your question with new info like what you put above, not answer in comments. That way all relevant info is available to any community member without the need to browse through comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost do this with the built-in Keyboard -> Text preferences.  Just add a definition for "{" and set it to "{}".  You actually have to hit another key (like space or return, or maybe anything) to make the "}" show up.

[image: shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Karabiner-Elements https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

You can find complex modification examples on
https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/

There you can search, for example "brackets", and you will find **Exchange square brackets and curly brackets**
https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#exchange_square_brackets_and_curly_brackets

When you click *Import* it will open Karabiner Elements and you just need to enable this rule.

Btw I copy `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` to my git repository so I can easily track changes I made in configuration.